# Include files over domains

Tags: php, apache, include

I am creating a server using ubuntu server hosting several different web sites.

I have several 'include' files that I would like to access from each of the different domains.

How would I go about this? Where should I store the shared files and what would be the best way to access them from the pages in the different sites.

I am using Apache, PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Please provide versions related to Apache, PHP, MySQL, Ubuntu.

Comment: Greetings are superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about superfluous greetings, I'm new and was just trying to be polite.

I'm using PHP 5, Apache 2, MySQL 5.

I should have included this originally, but I didn't; I'm using Ubuntu Server 15.10.

Can't get more detailed version numbers because the server is still being set up, and I'm not at the stage of making a phpinfo() page.